# C# is it possible to customise/override a class keeping its class name?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, namespaces, overriding

If I have a class namespaceX.classA which uses namespaceX.classB is it possible to customise/overide/extend classB without breaking ClassA by using the same namespace (?) and class name? If so please could you explain how I go about doing this?

Example extend by adding methods to ColumnHeaderCollection without breaking ListView

Comment: You could use Extension methods to add methods to the class, but you couldn't do much else.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @andicrook: Can you explain what you want to achieve by doing that, and perhaps we can suggest an alternate way?

Comment: How do you hope to distinguish between the two variants of a class with the exact same full name?  (and if you cannot distinguish between them, what is the point?)

Comment: @Kirk Woll Ruby has aliases I wondered if this was possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe. It depends on what you want to do and if you can modify class B.

Have a look at [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

**Extension Methods** let you create static methods in another static class (e.g. ClassBExtensions) that let you call them as if they were on ClassB. However you will not have access to any private or protected members in the extended class.

**Partial Classes** lets you add members directly to the class, but you need to be able to modify the source for ClassB since it needs to be declared partial in both places. Partial is really just a way to split a class definition into multiple files.

It sounds like you want an extension method.

```
 public static class ColumnHeaderCollectionExtensions
 {
     public static void NewMethod(this ColumnHeaderCollection collection)
     { 
         //do stuff here
     }
 }
```

You can then call it like:

```
myListView.Columns.NewMethod();
```

Comment: Many thanks a Extension Method seems to have solved the problem I was having.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.  You will get a duplicate definition, the only time two classes with the same name in the same namespace that are both visible is allowed is if they vary by the number of generic type arguments they accept.

That said, you *can* add functionality if the original class is marked as `partial`.

```
// file 1
namespace A
{
    public partial class B
    {
        public void AnOriginalMehtod() { ... }
    }
}

// file 2
namespace A
{
    public partial class B
    {
        public void AnotherMethod() { ... }
    }
}
```

And you can also add extension methods to an existing class to give it more functionality.

```
// file 1
namespace A
{
    public class B
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        { ... } 
    }
}

// file 2
namespace A
{
    public static class BExtensions
    {
        public static void SomeNewMethod(this B source)
        {
            // perform action on B
        }
    }
}
```

Partial classes let you flexibility by allowing you to divide a class into multiple files, but for this, to work the original class must be marked `partial`.

Extension methods are useful for adding functionality to existing classes or interfaces, but you must work with that interface or class through its public interface, you won't have access to private members.

Answer (score 2):

If the classes were in two separate namespace this would be possible.  You cannot have two types of the same name within a namespace.

```
namespace Foo
{
    class One : Bar.One
    {
    }
}

namespace Bar
{
    class One
    {
    }
}
```

One purpose of namespaces is to address naming conflicts of same-name types.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but take a look "partial class".

like

```
// this bit of the class in a file
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

//this bit in another file
public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```